# Winston console output not aligning

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, winston

Here is configuration:

```js
export default function getLogger(filename) {
    const config = {
        level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || "info",
        defaultMeta: {
            service: filename,
        },
        format: combine(
            colorize({ all: true }),
            timestamp({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS A",
            }),
            align(),
            printf(
                (info) =>
                    `[${info.timestamp}] [${info.service}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
            )
        ),
        transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
    };

    const logger = winston.createLogger(config);

    return logger;
}
```

Output:

```bash
[2024-03-16 05:13:34.799 PM] [app.js] info:     Database connected.
[2024-03-16 05:13:34.801 PM] [app.js] info:     Server running on port 3000
[2024-03-16 05:13:56.041 PM] [autenticate.js] error:    Autenticaion failed
```

As you can see output is not aligning properly. What am I doing wrong here?